# Zend Framework - Bootstrapping the database connection

Tags: php, zend-framework

For my current project, I want to dynamically load routes from a database. For this to work I need to fetch these results before the actual controllers are loaded (ofcourse).

I want to accomplish this by adding the results to the bootstrap. However, every tutorial I tried on this subject (the very few) didn't work.

What people suggested was to call

```
$this->bootstrap('db');
```

However, this resource doesn't seem to exist.

I have the db resource in my application.ini.

Anything that could make this work?

Thanks alot!

Comment: you should not load routes from databases. Store in a ini file and load it.

Comment: The line you've posted is the correct way to ensure the DB resource has been bootstrapped. How are you accessing the DB resource after doing that?

Comment: @emaillenin I'd say it's up to Jan to decide how the application stores its dynamic route information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want something like this in your `Bootstrap` class

```
public function _initDynamicRoutes()
{
    // bootstrap FrontController resource
    $this->bootstrap('frontController');

    // bootstrap DB resource
    $this->bootstrap('db');

    // get the router from the front controller
    $router = $this->getResource('frontController')->getRouter();

    // if you need the Zend_Db resource for direct calls...
    $db = $this->getResource('db');

    // fetch route data, add to $router
}
```

Comment: turns out it wasn't the code that made it crash; I put it inside my module's bootstrap.